# Use Self Variable in Decorator

Tags: python, class, oop, caching, self

I'm trying to use caching for my program, and I want to let the user choose how long the program should cache for.

```
class Parent:
    """The Parent Class, Do not import this."""
    def __init__(self, apiKey, cacheTime=300):
        self.key = apiKey
        self.time = cacheTime

class invalidApiKey(Exception):
    """The invalidApiKey error."""

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.message = args[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return "Invalid API Key (Register at https://url.com/register)- {0} ".format(
            self.message
        )

class Child(Parent):
    @cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=Parent.time))
    async def requestStats(self):
```

This is what my code is like, I've tried to use global variables, env variables, my own decorator -

```
class Parent:
    def cache(f):
        def wrapper(*args):
            return cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=args[0].time))
        return wrapper

class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.cache
    async def requestStats(self):
```

But I got a `ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <function cached.<locals>.decorator at 0x7f8b5d1e3c10>`, I'm unsure how to proceed now.

TL:DR - I want to use a self variable from a parent class to use as a parameter for a function in my child class. (If it makes a difference, I'm using [this library](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools) for caching)

Comment: Please show a [*complete*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) exception traceback, starting with the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, formatted as code.

Comment: That's not the error I'm interested in, I simply explained the error that I received when trying a possible fix, I just want to know how I can use a self variable in this context.
Here you go though
Edit - I'm not sure how to format code in a comment, here you go - https://mystb.in/PoorAccountHandy.sql

Comment: any updates? This is a bit important for me and I'm pretty interested to see how this could be managed :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seems to me that you're overcomplicating it. You seem to want a decorating that is parametrized at instantiation and not definition. If you want to use [`cached`](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#cachetools.cached), then you could do something like this:

```
from cachetools import TTLCache, cached

class Foo:
    
    def __init__(self, time=600):
        self.bar = cached(TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=time))(self.bar)
 
    def bar(self):
        ...
```

Here the undecorated method is created at definition, and then decorated with the respective parameters - `time` - at instantiation. But that's a bit awkward, and I think the better way is to use [`cachedmethod`](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#cachetools.cachedmethod):

```
from cachetools import TTLCache, cachedmethod

class Foo:
    
    def __init__(self, time=600):
        self.cache = TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=time)
 
    @cachedmethod(lambda self: self.cache)
    def bar(self):
        ...
```

Here the decoration happens at definition, but with a `cache`-function that refers to a cache object that is set up at instantiation - `self.cache` - with the individual parameteres.

But: Are you sure `cachetools` can handle `asyncio`?

Comment: I'm not sure if cachetools can handle asyncio but it seems to be working fine for now, I'll try your solution and be back tomorrow, ty!